# List.Cast<> error "is a method which is not valid in the given context"

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I have an abstract parent class which child classes that inherit from it. I have another class that contains many `List<>` types of the different child classes. I then have a method in another class that takes a parameter of `List<ParentType>` and just calls the methods that are declared abstract.

I'm having a problem using `List<T>.Cast<T2>` on the lists of the child classes. I'm getting the error:

> System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast(System.Collections.IEnumerable)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Does anybody know how to fix this error? Or do I have to reconstruct a list of type `List<ParentType>` and recast each item individually?

What I'm trying to do:
    public abstract class P {
        public int num;
        public abstract double addSections();
    }

```
public class A : P {
    public int num2;
    public A(int r, int n) {
        num = r;
        num2 = n;
    }
    public double addSections() { return (double)num + (double)num2; }
}

public class B : P {
    public double g;
    public B(int r, double k) {
        num = r;
        g = k;
    }
    public double addSections() { return (double)num + g; }
}

public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {
        List<A> listA;
        List<B> listB;
        //...
        helper(listA.Cast<P>()); //doesn't work
        helper(listB.Cast<P>().ToList()); //doesn't work either
    }

    public void helper(List<P> list) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post the code that gives you this error.

Comment: @Paul - indeed.  Without context we can't help you too much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In lieu of actually seeing your code so we can fix it, how about changing the method instead:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : ParentType
{
    ... 
}
```

Or if you're using C# 4 and .NET 4, this should be fine, as `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in `T` in .NET 4.

```
public void DoSomething(IEnumerable<ParentType> items)
{
    ... 
}
```

Do you really *need* the method to accept a `List<ParentType>`? After all, if you're going to call:

```
var parentList = childList.Cast<ParentType>().ToList();
```

and pass that into the method, then you've got two entirely separate lists by that point anyway.

By the way, another effect of the covariant of `IEnumerable<T>` is that in .NET 4 you can avoid the `Cast` call and just call:

```
var parentList = childList.ToList<ParentType>();
```

EDIT: Now that you've posted your code, it's simply a matter of not calling the `Cast` method *as* a method:

```
// This...
helper(listB.Cast<P>.ToList())

// should be this:
helper(listB.Cast<P>().ToList())
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with .NET 3.5 on this project. Your first example worked, thanks a lot! I had no idea you could do syntax like that in C#

Answer (score 2):

Now that you've added code, I see two potential problems:

1. You need to add parentheses when calling `Cast` e.g.

   `listA.Cast<P>()`

   `Cast` is not some special operator, it's an extension method like anything else.
2. Are those calls to `helper` actually at the class level, and not inside another method? That would be a problem too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, yes helper is at the same class level. I'll change the .Cast<>() calls too.